# Calculate 1 line value using 2 or more other lines

Tags: sql

I have the following query.

How this works my client sells kits. 
Each kit can contains 3 to 5 lines.

```
LINTYP = 6 - Kit Item
LINTYP = 7 - Components
```

The sequence should always be 6-7-7 where 6 represents the start of an new kit. There will always be 1 line that would contain an gross price. In the sample below there is 2 kits each containing 2 lines with an line status of 7

So what needs to happen is I need to calculate the missing  GROSPRI using LINTYP 6 and deducting all my LINTYP 7 lines

eq.

```
Grosprice on line 1 (Product 550412) = R1 795
Grosprice on line 3 (Product 501301) = R  185
Grosprice on line 2 (Product 650412) should be R 1795-185 = R1 610


----------------------------------------------------------------
|  Invoice No|  Product|  Line No|  Line Type|  Gross Price
----------------------------------------------------------------
|SI141000008|   550412| 1000|   6|  1795.00
----------------------------------------------------------------
|SI141000008|   650412| 2000|   7|  0.00 | This needs to be R1610
----------------------------------------------------------------
|SI141000008|   501301| 3000|   7|  185.00
---------------------------------------------------------------
|SI141000008|   550413| 4000|   6|  1855.00
--------------------------------------------------------------
|SI141000008|   650413| 5000|   7|  0.00 | This needs to be R1670
---------------------------------------------------------------
|SI141000008|   501301| 6000|   7|  185.00
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: What database are you using?  Also, SQL tables represent unordered sets.  How are the rows ordered?

Comment: What is the link between your ``Line Type 6` and `Line Type 7`?